# Prob. 13 (i), Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: The translate of an $F_\sigma$-set is also an $F_\sigma$-set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 13 (i), Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Show that the translate of every $F_\sigma$-set is also $F_\sigma$.

My Attempt:

> Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an $F_\sigma$-set, and let $y$ be any real number. We show that the set $E+y$, defined by
> $$
> E + y := \{ x+y \, | \, x \in E \},
> $$
> is also an $F_\sigma$-set.

> As $E$ is an $F_\sigma$-set, so there exists some countable collection $\left\{ E_k \right\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$  such that
> $$
> E = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k. \tag{1} 
> $$
> We show that
> $$
> E + y = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( E_k + y \right). \tag{2} 
> $$
> Let $x \in E + y$. Then $x = e+y$ for some $e \in E$, by (1) above this $e \in E_k$ for some $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, which implies that $x = e+y \in E_k + y$ for that same $k$, and hence $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( E_k + y \right)$, which shows that
> $$
> E+y \subset  \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( E_k + y \right).
> $$
> Conversely, let $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( E_k + y \right)$. Then this $x \in E_k + y$ for some $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, which implies that $x = e +y$ for some $e \in E_k$ for that same $k$ and that same $e \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k = E$ also, which in turn implies that $x = e+y \in E + y$, thus showing that
> $$
> \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( E_k + y \right) \subset E+y.
> $$
> Thus (2) above indeed holds.

> Let us fix some $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. We show that the set $E_k + y := \left\{ x+y \, | \, x \in E_k \right\}$ is also closed; for this we show that the corresponding set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$ is open; let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$. Then $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \not\in E_k + y$, which implies that $x \neq e + y$ for any element $e \in E_k$, that is, $x-y \not\in E_k$, which implies that $x-y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k$, and as this last set is open, so there exists a nonempty, bounded open interval $(a, b)$ such that
> $$
> x - y \in (a, b) \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k,
> $$
> which implies that
> $$
> x \in (a + y, b+ y) \subset \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y.  \tag{3} 
> $$
> Lastly we show that
> $$
> \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y = \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right). \tag{4} 
> $$
> Let $u \in \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y$. Then by definition $u = v + y$ for some element $v \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k$, that is, $u-y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k$, and so $u-y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u-y \not\in E_k$ and hence $u \not\in E_k+y$, but as $u \in \mathbb{R}$, so $u \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$, thus showing that
> $$
> \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y \, \subset \, \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right). 
> $$
> Conversely, let $u \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$. Then $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u \not\in E_k + y$, which implies that $u \neq e + y$ for any element $e \in E_k$, that is, $u-y \not\in E_k$, and thus $u-y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k$, which in turn implies that $u = (u-y)+y \in \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y$, thus showing that
> $$
>  \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right) \, \subset \, \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus E_k \right) + y.
> $$
> Thus (4) does indeed hold. Using (4) in (3) we can conclude that, for any element $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$, there exists a non-empty, bounded open interval $(a +y, b+y)$ such that
> $$
> x \in (a+y, b+y) \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right),
> $$
> thus showing that the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left( E_k + y \right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $E_k + y$ is closed.

> As each set $E_k + y$, for $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, is closed, so by (2) above we can conclude that the set $E + y$ is an $F_\sigma$-set.

Is my proof correct and clear in each and every step? Or, are there issues?

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to note that $t_y:x \to x+y$ is a homeomorphism ( even isometry) for each $y$ and homeomorphisms are closed bijections and so preserve $F_\sigma$ sets: $E+y = t_y[\bigcup_n F_n] = \bigcup_n t_y[F_n]$. You overcomplicate it.